# What could be preventing this certificate from installing?

Tags: vpn, azure, certificate

To access our Azure VMs over a VPN I need to install a certificate on client machines that need access. I was able to install it on someone else's laptop just fine, but am unable to install it on my own Windows 8 Desktop.

When I try to double click the certificate and use the dialog to install it, it tells me the password is wrong. I had someone test it out again on another computer and they said they were able to install it. I have installed several certificates on my own computer in the past and I am an Admin both in the Domain and on the local computer so I don't believe it would be related to any security issue.

Edit: I found something regarding an issue being logged in over Terminal Services with an account that doesn't have a profile on the local machine. My account does have a profile on the local machine, however I did also just try creating a new local admin acct on the machine and logging in with that, but that did not work either.

I have no clue what else could possibly cause it to say the password is wrong (although it is clearly correct and has been tested on multiple other machines). My google searches haven't turned up anything useful either.

Anyone here have an idea?

(And yes I have tried both copying and manually typing the password many times and have ensured there are no leading/trailing spaces when I enter it)

Comment: Can be this caused by keyboard layout? Did you try to type the password in notepad and type it in password box?

Comment: Yes, I tried both pasting and manually typing. And there is a checkbox that allows you to display the password so I could see that the characters were all correct. And the machines it worked on would have the same keyboard layout. Good thought though.

Comment: One more thing to check: when you open pfx in notepad, what you see? Does it look like a total mess of weird characters or a series of ASCII characters (base64 encoding)?

Comment: @Crypt32 Depends what I open it in. In Notepad it looks like chinese symbols. In Notepad++ it's more like ASCII but all the non-English characters along with various codes (e.g. [ACK] [BEL] [NUL] etc.)

Comment: One more thing to check: can `certutil` decode the PFX data: `certutil -dump pat\pfxfile.pfx`? When prompted, enter PFX passwod.

Comment: @Crypt32 Nope, that didn't work either. The company who manages our Azure stuff created a new cert today and it worked fine. Before that I did a screen share to assure them I was doing everything correctly and the first one just did not work in spite of the fact that it had worked for me on another computer and still works for them. Everyone was stumped but at least the new one works.